# How to extend the list of available Java Locales

Tags: java, locale

I am looking for a way to add more Locales to the Locales available in Java 1.6. But the Locales I want to create do not have ISO-3166 country codes, nor ISO-639 language codes. Is there any way to do this anyways? The Locales I want to add only differ in the language names, but the smaller an ethnic group is, the more picky they get about their identity ;-)

So I thought about extending an existing Locale, something like

```
UserDefinedLocale extends Locale { 
   UserDefinedLocale (Locale parentLocale) {...}
}
```

but java.util.Locale is final, which makes it especially hard to hack something around...

So, is the idea that the list of Java Locales is exhaustive? Am I the first to miss some more Locales?

Answer (score 6):

Read the javadoc for [java.util Locale](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

It says : 
"Create a Locale object using the constructors in this class: "

It also says : 
"Because a Locale object is just an identifier for a region, no validity check is performed when you construct a Locale"

It also says :
"A Locale is the mechanism for identifying the kind of object (NumberFormat) that you would like to get. The locale is just a mechanism for identifying objects, not a container for the objects themselves"

And finally, the javadoc for the getAvailableLocales() method says :
"The returned array represents the union of locales supported by the Java runtime environment and by installed LocaleServiceProvider implementations"

So you just have to invent a language code which is not in the standard list, and use it as an identifier for your locale.

Comment: _"So you just have to invent a language code which is not in the standard list, and use it as an identifier for your locale."_ - did you miss the bit you quoted about installing a `LocaleServiceProvider`?

Comment: I agree it's a shortcut. But since the OP didn't explicitely explain what he meant by "extending the list of available locales", I suspected that what he wanted just needed him to instantiate a new one. Using ResourceBundle doesn't need anything other than a new Locale. Number and date formatting could reuse the rules from another language. He would then only have to use a new country code or variant code.

Answer (score 3):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111226/missing-locales-in-java/2111649#2111649):

> ...You can plug in support for additional locales via the SPIs (described [here](http://blogs.oracle.com/naotoj/entry/about_the_locale_sensitive_services)). For example, to provide a date formatter for a new locale, you would do it by implementing a [`DateFormatProvider`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/spi/DateFormatProvider.html) service. You might be able to do this by decorating an existing implementation - I'd have a look at the [ICU4J](http://icu-project.org/) library to see if it provides the support you want.

Comment: Thanks. Sadly manipulating every users JRE is not an option for my application:
"Since the Locale Sensitive Services SPIs are based on the standard Java Extension Mechanism, you can package them as a JAR file (with a few tricks in its MANIFEST file, which can be found in here) and place it in the extension directory."