# Implementing user defined Native locale in Java

Tags: java, localization, locale, resourcebundle

As a part of localization I am now trying to implement locale strings for `Native languages(India).`

While searching I found an solution on Stack overflow that we can create `user defined locales.`

[How to extend the list of available Java Locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716147/how-to-extend-the-list-of-available-java-locales)

I created my own class ,Some thing like

```
IndianLocale extends Locale { 
   IndianLocale (Locale Locale.En) ....
}
```

I have `resource bundles` with me for each `language`.But i am missing that where i have to map these bundles to Locale (So that when i request  to a `locale` it will return a corresponding localise `string`).

Answer (score 0):

As answers in that other post suggest, a `Locale` is little more than a formatted sequence of strings.  If you already know your target locale, you can simply create a ResourceBundle for it based on its name, such as `MyApplicationStrings_hi_IN_someregion.properties`, regardless of whether that locale is known to Java.

If you don't know the name of the `Locale`, write a short Java program that does `System.out.println(Locale.getDefault().toLanguageTag());` and run the program on a machine which is known to be set to the locale of interest.