# Struts 2 (version 2.3.28) only accepts registered locales

Tags: java, struts2, internationalization, interceptor

In Struts 2 version 2.3.28, the `i18n` interceptor only accepts the locales which are registered to jvm, the list which is returned by `Locale.getAvailableLocales()`.

Well, although I can extend the list of available Java Locales, as mentioned [How to extend the list of available Java Locales](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716147/how-to-extend-the-list-of-available-java-locales), is it any short way that set this interceptor to accept all strings as locale (for example `fa_IR` ) ?!

Just a note: Setting the default locale to `fa_IR` ( `<constant name="struts.locale" value="fa_IR" />` ) works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you have to create your own interceptor that extends `i18n` and override this method

```
 protected Locale getLocaleFromParam(Object requestedLocale) {
        Locale locale = null;
        if (requestedLocale != null) {
            locale = (requestedLocale instanceof Locale) ?
                    (Locale) requestedLocale :
                    LocalizedTextUtil.localeFromString(requestedLocale.toString(), null);
            if (locale != null && LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                LOG.debug("applied request locale=#0", locale);
            }
        }

        if (locale == null) {
            locale = Locale.getDefault();
        }
        return locale;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, the `if (locale == null)` statment must be removed too, or it will be always set to default :)