# Locale doesn't exists in Java

Tags: java, locale

I am from Turkmenistan and I used JDatePicker to get a date. Is it possible to use the Turkmen locale in Java?

Comment: Are you sure your locale isn't supported? - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html

Comment: What did you try? What was the result? What didn't work?

Comment: @mre: Cannot find "turkmen" (tk-TM) on that list, so I think it really does not ship with Java.

Comment: I tried setLocale(new Locale("tm")); but it shows in english

Comment: @serdar The language code is "tk" so it should be `new Locale("tk")` or `new Locale("tk", "TM")`. But it still doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to add a complete new Locale to the JRE (sounds like a lot of work), but you can [localize the Swing components that you need with arbitrary message bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671868/how-can-i-add-localization-to-jfilechooser-for-a-locale-that-is-not-supported-by). And I suppose you would need to also write a custom DateFormatter.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to this answer [Missing Locales in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111649/211149), that give you a clue to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.util.TimeZone`.
Check your nearest country's timezone using the below code

```
for(String locale : java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs())
        {
            System.out.println(locale);
        }
```

convert your date picker time to this timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Locale is a final class, with a predefined list of Locales.  I suggest you try finding a Locale which works for your situation.

The only other option is to modify a copy of the Locale class and add it to your bootclasspath or endorsed directory.